# Ruby On Rails Model Assert Test failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Currently learning ROR via The Odin Project Curriculum. As part of the 'PROJECT: Building with active record' I have set up three basic models: User, Post, Comments.

In both Post and Comments my basic 'Post/Comments is valid' test is failing(false expecting truthy), but all specific tests pass, e.g. code for PostTest:

```
require 'test_helper'

class PostTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # test "the truth" do
  #   assert true
  # end

  def setup
    @post = Post.new(title: "Hello World", body: "Hello world, it's nice to 
meet you", user_id: 1)
  end

  test "Post is valid" do
    assert @post.valid?
  end

  test "Post title is not blank" do
    @post.title = ""
    assert_not @post.valid?
  end

  test "Post title is less than 40 char" do
    @post.title = "a"*51
    assert_not @post.valid?
  end

  test "Post body is not blank" do
    @post.body = ""
    assert_not @post.valid?
  end

 test "Post has user_id" do
   @post.user_id = ""
   assert_not @post.valid?
 end
end
```

The reason I am confused is that if I use rails console to manually create the same Post as in the `#setup` above then the `valid?` method correctly returns `true`. Additionally the User model setup with exactly the same formation of `#setup` and `user is valid` tests passes fine. The only difference I see is that User `has_many :posts` where as the Posts `belong_to :user`

For ref the Post model is:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  validates :title, presence: true, length: {maximum: 40}
  validates :body, presence: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true

  belongs_to :user 
  has_many :comments

end
```

Comment: Can you run this again `@post = Post.new(title: "Hello World", body: "Hello world, it's nice to 
meet you", user_id: 1)` in console and check if it is valid there?

Comment: Double checked now on another computer : Console `True` and saves. `Rails test` - `Expected false to be truthy`

Comment: Ok. Here is a way to debug. Inside your `test`, do: `@post.valid?; assert_empty(@post.errors.full_messages)`. This should show you the error messages causing the failure.

Comment: Thanks! The error was `User must exist`. After `user.create` in the setup everything worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using fixtures for your users or how do you know a user record with id 1 exists?

if you are using fixtures, you should create a user in your setup:

```
def setup
  user = users(:default_user)
  @post = Post.new(
    title: "Hello World", 
    body: "Hello world, it's nice to meet you", 
    user: user
  )
end
```

See more on fixtures:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#the-low-down-on-fixtures

Comment: Thanks - I just reached this conclusion from Jagdeep's  comment above as you posted. Not studied fixtures yet, but after creating a user in the setup everything works. Appreciated.